# Wi-Fi dongle not working

Tags: networking, wifi

I have followed numerous tutorials to get my Wi-Fi dongle working on my Raspberry Pi, and when I use this command:

```
iwconfig
```

I get what almost all the tutorials show me, but I still can't get to Google or any other website. Here is what I get:

[image: iwconfig outcome]

I can also post my `/etc/network/interfaces` file if needed.

Here is the ouput of `ifconfig -a`:

[image]

Comment: Can you also paste the output of `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: @Lawrence I edited my question and inclued the output.

Comment: Try another PSU? My experience with these types of issues is lack of power

Comment: @PhilVallone I used a wall outlet rather than a battery pack, and it still didn't work.

Comment: You do not have an IP address. Post the output of `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Is it receiving enough power. Try a Power hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WiFi dongle is receiving a strong signal from your router. But the router has not yet assigned an IP address to your RPi's WiFi LAN device. Most likely that is due to a misconfiguration of your /etc/network/interfaces file. If you are using a WPA secured wireless network then your interfaces file should look something like:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary (wired) network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The wifi (wireless) network interface
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "ssid"
        wpa-psk "password"
```

You will, of course, need to substitute your router's SSID and password for what is shown above. Also, be sure to reboot your RPi after making any changes to the interfaces file.

If your WiFi router is using a hidden SSID then you will need to use a different definition in your interfaces file. Likewise if you are not using WPA for security.

For WEP you might want to take a look at this post: http://jeffskinnerbox.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/wifi-support-on-raspberry-pi/

For WEP the suggested interfaces file text is as follows:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary (wired) network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The wifi (wireless) network interface
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
       wireless-essid YOUR_SSID
       wireless-key YOUR_WEP_KEY
```

Comment: My wifi uses WEP security, so do i just use `wep-ssid` and `wep-psk`

Comment: I added suggested interfaces text for WEP. I'd suggest giving that a try. Also the link I added might have some helpful troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Ah, @LukeK - WEP security is virtually no security. Have a look here, http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2007/04/new-attack-cracks-wep-in-record-time/ and consider using WPA2 instead.

Comment: No need to restart. Run `sudo service networking restart`

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer a static IP address:

I had my eth0 set to static so the wlan0 would not not work in [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) mode. The fix was to assign a static IP address to the wlan0 like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary (wired) network interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# The Wi-Fi (wireless) network interface
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0  inet static
address 192.168.0.51
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    wpa-ssid "Wifi"
    wpa-psk "password"
```