# Email Notification on RPi_2

Tags: pi-2

I am new to Raspberry pi. 
I have done some simple programs on it related to GPIO and want to move forward to get my email notification on pi with some LED indications.
i did surfing as well and found some ways do it.
But I am not able to Download the necessary files i tried following command

1. sudo apt-get install exim4
2. [imapclient][1]

but both are showing the same error

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/tushar/programs/working $ sudo apt-get install exim4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light heirloom-mailx
Suggested packages:
  mail-reader eximon4 exim4-doc-html exim4-doc-info spf-tools-perl swaks
Recommended packages:
  mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light heirloom-mailx
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,406 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,259 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main exim4-config all 4.80-7
  Could not connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (5.153.225.207). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main exim4-base armhf 4.80-7
  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main exim4-daemon-light armhf 4.80-7
  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main exim4 all 4.80-7
  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Err mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main heirloom-mailx armhf 12.5-2
  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-config_4.80-7_all.deb  Could not connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (5.153.225.207). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-base_4.80-7_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4-daemon-light_4.80-7_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4_4.80-7_all.deb  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Failed to fetch mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/h/heirloom-mailx/heirloom-mailx_12.5-2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
pi@raspberrypi ~/tushar/programs/working $
```

Please help me asap,so that i can move forward. suggestions are welcome.

Note: I removed http:// from links as i am not having 10 reputation

Comment: Try again later. It is not uncommon for some of the repository to be unavailable, particularly on weekends. Are you running Wheezy? This is unsupported.

Comment: how to check this ?@Milliways

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: its wheezy @Milliways

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to RPi board. Did you check your internet connection? I assume your internet connection is broken. If you're using WiFi dongle you may check [Wi-Fi dongle not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22349/wi-fi-dongle-not-working). Check your connection and comment your status for better help Tushar.

**Note:**

You better upgrade your package list at least every day:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Regards

Comment: my connection is working and pi@raspberrypi ~/tushar/programs/working $ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.3.14) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: but working from my office(work) system . Is issue regarding this ?

Comment: As i see you can not connect to raspbian.org so i think your internet connection is broken or your network firewall is not allowing this for this. Can you try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: sorry i missed writing about sudo apt -get update but this also showing the same like this err(could not connect to ...(111: connection refused)

Comment: That's weird. You can connect to internet but can't connect to RPi's repos. Is your current network isolated via firewall or something ?

Comment: maybe as i am using office network. but how to resolve this ?please help!

Comment: Can you ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org ?

Comment: showing like this ..pi@raspberrypi ~/tushar/programs/working $ ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org
PING mirrordirector.raspbian.org (5.153.225.207) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: This is really weird situation. There are 3 possible issues : 
o No access to the Internet
o No DNS or pointing at a name server that is not working
o Ports blocked
I suggest try another place's network not isolated via firewall etc. and try update, upgrade and install again Tushar

Comment: I cant take this Rpi_2 kit to my Room so working in office on weekend but getting this issue

Comment: Lets try adding dns type `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and add lines to end (each of new line) `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` and save it and reboot your RPi

Comment: not able to save this file resolv.conf tried CTR+X and Y saved but after rebooting its  without nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: still I am facing the same error. please help!

Comment: [`5.153.225.207`](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=5.153.225.207) is indeed the correct IP for Raspbian repo, so your answer is unlikely to help